# Java - Thread doesn't want to start

Tags: java, multithreading

I have this console application, but for some reason the thread's run() method doesn't want to start. The code seems long for the first time but I tried to organize it as much as I can.

The result output:

```
eThread starting!!
```

So it seems that CarManager.startFunctionalities() gets executed, but the line eThread.start() is not executed at all because the line "started" is not printed out.

Here is the sourcecode.

The main class:

```
package rpicar.android;


public class AndroidEmulator{


    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        CarManager cm = new CarManager ("localhost");
    }
}
```

CarManager:

```
package rpicar.android;

import rpicar.common.Direction;
import rpicar.common.EnvironmentData;


public class CarManager {
    private  MotorManager mManager;
    private final String RPIADDRESS = "localhost";
    private Thread mThread; //motor
    private EnvironmentManager eManager;
    private Thread eThread;
    public CarManager(String rpiAddress) {
        //initialize MotorManager
        mManager = new MotorManager(RPIADDRESS);
        //Make a thread for the Motor commands
        mThread = new Thread(mManager);
        //Initialize EnvironmentManager
        eManager = new EnvironmentManager(RPIADDRESS);
        //Makea thread for collecting EnvironmentData
        eThread = new Thread (eThread);
        startFunctionalities();
    }

    public void move(Direction d){
        this.mManager.setDirection(d);
    }

    public EnvironmentData getCurrentEnvironmentData(){
        return this.eManager.getCurrentEnvironmentData();
    }

    private void startFunctionalities(){
        //Start MotorManager for sending movement commands when needed.
        //mThread.start();
        //Start EnvironmentManager to collect EnvironmentData
        System.out.println("eThread starting!! ");
        eThread.start();
    }
}
```

EnvironmentManager:

```
package rpicar.android;

import rpicar.common.CarComponent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import rpicar.common.EnvironmentData;


public class EnvironmentManager extends CarComponent implements Runnable{
    private EnvironmentData currentEnvironmentData;

    public EnvironmentManager(String rpiAddress) {
        super(rpiAddress, 2176, true);
        this.currentEnvironmentData = new EnvironmentData();
    }

    public synchronized EnvironmentData getCurrentEnvironmentData() {
        return currentEnvironmentData;
    }

    public synchronized void setCurrentEnvironmentData(EnvironmentData currentEnvironmentData) {
        this.currentEnvironmentData = currentEnvironmentData;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("eThread started!! ");
        super.connect();
        while(true){
            try {
                this.setCurrentEnvironmentData((EnvironmentData) super.in.readObject());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                super.connect();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(EnvironmentManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }    
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this `eThread = new Thread (eThread);` be `eThread = new Thread (eManager);`? At the moment you are passing null to the constructor, meaning that the run method does nothing...

Comment: The statement in run method is printing, then isn't the thread started ?

Comment: @AnshulJain no it prints `starting`, not `started`.

Comment: your title made me laugh the crap out of me!!

Comment: @assylias true, I fixed it and now it works. But how can I give your answer a green thick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create your instance of `eThread`, you accidentally pass the thread itself to the constructor (or according to the order of the operations, you pass `null`).

You should pass `eManager` to the constructor instead.

> ```
> eThread = new Thread (eThread);
> ```

Would become

```
eThread = new Thread (eManager);
```

You can protect yourself in the future from this mistake by making the `eThread` a final field, so you cannot use it before you declare it.